# Can't get post value

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

i have problem with the post value in my form

i show you my code and see if you can help me

```
<script src="//netsh.pp.ua/upwork-demo/1/js/typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#ville').on('change', function(){
          var id_ville = this.value;
           $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               url: "lycee.php",
               data: 'id_ville=' + id_ville,
               success: function(result){
                    $("#lycee").html(result);
                }
            });

            $('input.lycee').typeahead({
                name: 'lycee',
                remote: 'lycee.php?query=%QUERY'
            });
        });
    })
</script>
<script >
```

and this is my php part code

```
$id_ville = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id_ville']);

if($id_ville!='') {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
        $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
        $sql = $conn->query ("SELECT nom_lycee 
            FROM ville_lycee   
            INNER JOIN ville ON ville.id_ville = ville_lycee.id_ville 
            INNER JOIN lycee ON lycee.id_lycee = ville_lycee.id_lycee 
            WHERE ville.id_ville = '" . $id_ville . "' 
                AND lycee.nom_lycee LIKE '%{$query}%' ");

        $options = "<label value=''></label>";
        $array = array();

        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            $array[] = array (
               'label' => $row['nom_lycee'],  
                'value' => $row['nom_lycee'],
            );
        }

        echo json_encode ($array);
    }
}
```

the problem is that i need the id_ville value first and then the Query to filtre

Comment: Show us the form markup.

Comment: What is `$query` ? Is jQuery available ?

Comment: You are not sending any parameter `query` with your AJAX request, so your PHP script does _nothing_ even if id_ville isn’t empty …

Comment: Why are you making  two different requests?  Shouldn't id_ville just be part of the typeahead request?

Comment: @Daniel - The Ajax request has `type: "post"` so it is a POST request. However, the OP doesn't pass the parameter `query`, which they require in their PHP-code.

Comment: You are mixing different libraries for your mysql connection, cou need to change that! Please note that the function `mysql_real_escape_string()` is part of the old, outdated and long decrecated mysql extension that should not be used any more. You _are_ actually using the mysqli extension already, but make the mistake to still not use "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding" which actually would make the motivation to escape arguments using mentioned function completely obsolet. As it stands now your code is wide open to sql injection attacks...

Comment: @PatrickQ yes id_ville is part of it

Comment: @arkascha the problem is that i don't get the value of $_POST['id_ville']

Comment: when  i do this i get all fields 
FROM ville_lycee   
            INNER JOIN ville ON ville.id_ville = ville_lycee.id_ville 
            INNER JOIN lycee ON lycee.id_lycee = ville_lycee.id_lycee 
            WHERE  lycee.nom_lycee LIKE '%{$query}%' ");

Comment: @AbdoMErzouk No, id_ville is currently _not_ part of the typeahead request that you are making.  That is the problem (or at least part of it).  You are manually making an ajax request, and _then_ the typeahead function is triggering one as well.

Comment: @AbdoMErzouk FWIW, you appear to be using a _significantly_ outdated version of typeahead.js

Comment: @PatrickQ typehead is working with a brut request of sql but when i add the id_ville as a condition it gives me "Undefined index: id_ville"

Comment: @AbdoMErzouk You're obviously struggling to understand what I'm saying.  I'm sorry I can't help you.

Comment: Sure, that is certainly possible. I made a general remark to help you see that your code is highly insecure.

Comment: @PatrickQ i didn't say anything i m just searching for a suggestion to solve that